# WPF Bind once and never update?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ListView and a GridView that lists users in an application by names. Whenever the user selects an user to edit, I add a new tab to a TabControl, and bind all editable properties to the WPF controls.

However, when the user is editing in the Edit Tab, the information in the List (specifically, the name field) is also being updated.

Currently I'm making a copy of the object to be edited and leaving the original so it doesn't update the ListView, but isn't there a better/easier way to do this?

I've tried setting the `Binding Mode=OneWay`, didn't work, and also `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit` in the GridView but also didn't work.

Is there any easier way to do this?

**Edit**: The way I implemented my INotifyPropertyChanged class is part of the issue, since I have this:

```
public partial class MyTabControl : UserControl
{
    public MyTabControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Here, DataContext is a List<Users>
        //Users being my Model from the Database
        //Some of it's properties are bound to a GridView
        //User doesn't implement INPC
    }

    public void OpenTab(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        User original = (sender as Button).DataContext as User;

        // - This will create a new ViewModel below with the User I'm sending
        MyTabControl.AddTab(original);
    }
}
```

And my ViewModel of Users is:

```
public class UserViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public User Original { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get { return Original.Name; } set { Original.Name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); } }

    public UserViewModel(User original)
    {
        Original = original ?? new User();
    }

    // - INPC implementation
}
```

Since my ViewModel is the one reporting the property changes, I didn't expect my original `User` to report it as well to the GridView.

Comment: How are you binding the data? I would expect a one-way binding to do what you want. But perhaps you are binding backwards from what one might expect. In that case, you might want `BindingMode.OneWayToSource` instead. Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not possible to know for sure what's needed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The `Mode=OneWay` causes the information flow to go from the bound data entity to the target UI property only, any change to the UI property will not be bound back.

The reason why the UI content is changing is because the underlying property is read/write (i.e. has a getter and a setter) and is notifying any value change (due to the implementation of the [INPC interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Presuming that it is a list of `User` objects you've bound to the GridView, you have two simple options to fix this. Which one is best depends on how much scope for change you have:

- change the current `Name` property on the `User` object, remove the setter for it. Replace the setter with a method to set the property (i.e. `SetUserName(string name)`) which then sets the private member variable. Or pass the name as an argument to the constructor of the `User` entity.
- create a new property with only a getter which returns the name and set your binding to that; i.e. `public string UserName { get { return Name; }}`. As there is only a getter there will be no notification of this property, so if the name does change it won't be propagated via this new property.